# Pandas - Build a count crosstab from one column (crosstab or pivot)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, crosstab

I have a df where I want to identify double counting. I have a column of what should be uniquely identified values (but are not). I have another column that maps this ID to a location. I want to find the mappings with the most double counts. How can I pivot this data as follows:

```
             food     drink    silverware
food          23       7        8 

drink          7       83       3

silverware     8       3        89
```

Here is an example of what the df could look like:

```
id           category
1             food
2             drink
3             food
3             drink
4             drink
4             silverware
5             silverware
```

Comment: Can you provide a [working exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?